# Can't debug GoogleTest when use static library

Tags: c++, googletest

I put the `gtest src` in to my project folder like below and wish to debug the testcase in VS.

```
│  CMakeLists.txt
│  
├─google test source code
│              
├─src
│  │  CMakeLists.txt
│  └─ CObject.h
│          
└─UnitTest
        TCObject.cpp
```

Everything is fine, I use the `Cmake` to generate the VS project file and open it in `Visual Studio 2015`.The CmakeLists.txt is like below

```
PROJECT (BVH)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.00)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
INSTALL(DIRECTORY src/shaders DESTINATION build/bin)
INSTALL(DIRECTORY scene DESTINATION build/bin)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src bin)

################################
# GTest
################################
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY (googletest)
ENABLE_TESTING()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

################################
# Unit Tests
################################
# Add test cpp file
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{GLM})
ADD_EXECUTABLE( runUnitTests UnitTest/TCObject.cpp )
# Link test executable against gtest & gtest_main
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(runUnitTests gtest gtest_main )
ADD_TEST( runUnitTests runUnitTests )
```

And here is my testcase

```
#include<gtest/gtest.h>
#include"../src/CObject.h"
#include<glm/glm.hpp>

TEST(TestCObject,TestInitial){
    CCube *cube=new CCube(glm::vec3(1,2,3),2);
    EXPECT_EQ(2,cube->bounds.pMax[0]);
}
```

**Problem 1:I can only run my testcase if I set the gtest's and gtest_main's runtime library to `MDd` instead of it's own `MTd`, I don't know if there is any problem in the future**

**Problem 2:If I choose to set a breakpoint and debug it, the window is just flash and disappear.Only if I change the cmake option `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES` of `gtest` and copy the `dll` file into the place where my executable testfile locate, then I can debug my testcase**

But the problem is I must copy the `dll` file everytime. So I wonder if there's a way to debug in the static libraries **(Problem 1)**  or I can set the target space of gtest to reach to the place where my testfile locate **(Problem 2)**.

Comment: How did you statically link the gtest lib to your project?